# Emoji does not render correctly when yanked from Neovim and pasted into a macOS GUI app like TextEdit

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, macos

**My issue**

I am new to Neovim/Vim, and I am using the [Neovim from Scratch](https://github.com/LunarVim/Neovim-from-scratch) config as a starting point. It works well for me for the most part. I have a peculiar encoding issue affecting emoji that prevents emoji from rendering properly from the moment I yank them in Neovim.

Instead of seeing a line like this: "I have a  (cake) emoji and a  (apple)  emoji"

I see a line that looks like this: "I have a üéÇ (cake) emoji and a üçè (apple)  emoji"

My question: How do I resolve this emoji rendering issue? Alternatively, where should I look next to troubleshoot this issue?

**Steps to reproduce**

- I have text in Neovim that includes an emoji character;
- My test used this line that I created in TextEdit in plain text mode: "I have a  (cake) emoji and a  (apple)  emoji";
- I copied that from TextEdit using the `CMD c` command, and pasted it into Neovim using `CMD v`, and it rendered correctly;
- I then copy the text from Neovim using `y` in Normal mode, and paste it into TextEdit, and I see "I have a üéÇ (cake) emoji and a üçè (apple)  emoji";
- I did the same test from the command line in iTerm (I've tried the same thing in the Kitty terminal emulator with the same result) where I copied the same time in iTerm2 to TextEdit, and the line pastes correctly;
- I noticed that if I copy the line from TextEdit using `CMD c` and then paste into Neovim using `p` in Normal mode, I see the incorrectly rendered text.

Here is a video demonstrating the issue: https://cln.sh/VPzgydIs5CDYj4cPcXkl

An interesting observation is that if I have the same file open in Neovim and VS Code and update on either side, the other app accurately displays the content with the emoji. This issue only seems to manifest when I use the Vim `y` and `p` commands.

**My system**

- My encoding in Neovim and iTerm2 is set to UTF-8.
- I am using macOS 12.1 and Neovim 6.1 (the issue was present in Neovim 6.0 too).
- I am using the Nerd Font modified version of JetBrains Mono
- As I mentioned above, I am also using the Neovim from Scratch config for Neovim as I'm a newbie, and this gives me a great foundation to use Neovim.

I'd appreciate any help or pointers here. I could abandon the use of the emoji entirely, although I tend to use them in my daily flow so I'd prefer to be able to keep using them.

Comment: Is it possible you didn't copy the whole sequence? Or could the app you pasted into not be configured correctly? I just pasted the  out of your question into vim, `yy`'d it out, and pasted it into TextEdit, all without trouble. One other place to start: [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: Hi @D.BenKnoble - Thank you for your feedback. I just tried that again. I pasted the line with the emoji from the post above into Neovim using `CMD v`. I then used `SHIFT v` (so `V`) to select the line, and then `yy` to yank it.

When I pasted it into TextEdit, I had the same issue. Interestingly when I paste using `p` in Neovim, the result replaces the emoji with `??`.

Comment: I'll work through the troubleshooting steps. As I mentioned in the video, I also reproduced this in Vim on my laptop. It's possible I have something installed there too, so I'll double check that. If anything, it should be a good control test because my customizations are in Neovim (so `.nvimrc` and the other config files in `~/.config/nvim/`.

Comment: I tested this with Vim after opening it using this command: `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N` and the emoji work as they should. Here's another demo: https://cln.sh/7z4azKr1wkkgBNHsgNN4

So this seems to be something about my Neovim configuration. I don't suppose anyone has suggestions where to look?

Comment: The debugging steps (commenting half at a time, for example), should apply equally well to neovim as to vim

Comment: Thank you, good advice. I'll work on that. I'm actually doing a course on troubleshooting and debugging at the moment so this is good practice!  Thank you for your advice. Appreciate it.

Comment: I seem to have found the culprit. It is the `clipboard = "unnamed"` in my `options.lua` file, [here](https://github.com/LunarVim/Neovim-from-scratch/blob/7a082a3306b27d59257ce9bc826ab4dc64f69854/lua/user/options.lua#L3). I have the same issue if I use `unnamedplus`.

I just ran `:echo has('clipboard')` and received a `1` return.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer if you found a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that I found the solution for my issue. I noticed [this issue in the Neovim repo](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2386) about the `!locale` options in Neovim. I checked mine and I had the following:

```
:!locale
[No write since last change]
LANG="en_IL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

I'm in Israel, hence the locale. I also noticed a suggestion to add `export LANG=C` to my shell settings in [this AppleExchange discussion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83428/lang-variable-wrong-in-iterm2-wheres-the-bug/83433#83433) so I added that to my `.zshrc` file. My resulting `!locale` output is now this:

```
:!locale
[No write since last change]
LANG="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

This seems to have resolved the issue for me. Copying and pasting with emoji seems to work for me now.

Comment: Results may be even better if you set LC_ALL to the Israel/utf8 locale

Comment: Setting `LANG="C"` looks wrong to me, it's essentially disabling locales... Setting `LC_ALL` is usually bad, since it overrides every other individual locale choice... It seems to me that the problem is with `LC_CTYPE`, the value "UTF-8" looks invalid to me, I'm fairly certain that's not a valid choice. I think setting `LANG="en_IL.UTF-8"` is probably the best way to fix that. (Not sure whether that would fix your problem or not, but that's my best guess here.)

Comment: I tried to set `LC_ALL` to my actual locale in my `.zshrc` and received an error when I sourced the updated file to the effect that the declaration wasn't appropriate in that file. 

Comment: @filbranden Thanks for your suggestion. Would I declare that in my `.zshrc` in much the same way? Happy to try that too. I'm just glad I can copy/paste properly now

Comment: Yes, of course, getting the issue solved is worth it! So this discussion is a bit more about perhaps what's the *cleanest* or *purest* approach (and possibly one that will avoid problems in other applications.) The Apple StackExchange discussion mentioned preferences under "iTerm: Preferences > Profiles > Terminal > Set locale variables automatically", I wonder if tweaking (disabling?) those would have some effect... They also mention global system preferences for locale. Maybe take a look at those and perhaps post on the Apple SE about how to set them right?

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid setting Locale preferences in a .zshrc or similar file. In Linux I know you can set it in a `~/.i18n` file, not sure whether on Macs that works or not... I do have a Mac around I can use for testing, but it often takes me a while to get it and get it working to reproduce an issue, so you might have more luck with other Mac power users on how to set this up correctly...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'll do some more research on this.